# Why did DOS-based Windows require HIMEM.SYS to boot?

Tags: ms-dos, memory, windows

My understanding is that all versions of Microsoft Windows that ran on top of DOS — that is, the lineage from Windows 1.0 up to Windows ME, even though the reliance on DOS diminished over time — required `HIMEM.SYS`, the extended memory manager for DOS, to be loaded in order to be able to start in protected mode (thus, from Windows 3.1 on, to be able to start at all).

Contemporary documentation used to make it very clear that the driver was mandatory, but did not elaborate on why it was so. HIMEM.SYS was supposed to provide XMS memory to real mode DOS programs, but since the protected mode Windows kernel was to take over memory management and access all installed memory directly, relying on a 16-bit DOS driver would seem rather nonsensical, especially considering that XMS itself could not be used to access memory arbitrarily but in pieces that had to be copied back and forth between conventional and extended memory.

So, what was the role of HIMEM.SYS with Windows? If it was used just as an intermediary for the Windows loader (which had to be a real mode DOS program) to be able to stuff the insides of Windows into memory before kernel start, how was the switching over to Windows managing the memory accomplished? Did this require HIMEM.SYS to "know" and cooperate with Windows in some way?

Comment: I don't know enough to provide a real answer, but ensuring that HIMEM.SYS is installed means there is no other and incompatible driver managing the extended memory, as Windows may use the data structures of HIMEM.SYS when transitioning to handle it itself. Also Windows loader/startup code could just allocate all XMS memory available from HIMEM driver, load some large kernel/driver pnode code there, and simply go into protected mode and jump to run the loaded pmode/kernel/driver code which manages the allocated area from that point onwards to Window and applications.

Comment: I don't think Windows 1.0 needed himem.sys https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12651/7146 (And that suggest windows 2's himem.sys is not XMS)

Comment: @mmmmmm yes, `HIMEM.SYS` was added with Windows 2.1, earlier versions didn’t use XMS.

Comment: It is not "required to boot". But you have to install it at boot to if it will be used later.

Comment: 9x, ME and the NT series are not based on DOS. Those are real multitasking OSs which run on multitasking CPUs. DOS never supported real multitasking. The kernel of 9x and ME is completely new and not based on DOS. You can read [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/25632/25365): _By 9x DOS wasn't much more than a boot loader._. Perhaps 9x and ME used DOS as bootloader and supported DOS programs for compatibility. But hey are not based on DOS. More can be read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071224-00/?p=24063).

Comment: Also related: <https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160808-00/?p=94036> and <https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160503-00/?p=93397>

Answer (score 38):

Windows in protected mode [requires an XMS driver](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/076/Q76850/) — `HIMEM.SYS` is the one provided by Microsoft, but others can be used¹ (and [the Windows Me kernel includes its own XMS driver](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24357/79)). The role of the XMS driver depends on the version of Windows and the mode it’s run in. The basic requirement is that Windows needs to be able to access extended memory, and it needs to do so without losing anything loaded before it (such as the SMARTDrive disk cache).

At the XMS level, there isn’t much cooperation involved: Windows allocates all the available XMS memory (after asking programs such as SMARTDrive to free some memory up if appropriate), and then handles XMS requests itself. XMS includes the necessary mechanism, a chain of hooks such that the calling address for XMS never changes, but the latest XMS handler ends up being called first. This allows Windows to handle XMS requests for programs which were loaded before it started. A good reference for this is Geoff Chappell’s *DOS Internals*.

Given that Windows, at least in enhanced mode, includes its own XMS handler, one may wonder why it needs to rely on `HIMEM.SYS` or another driver at all. I suspect that this is to avoid duplication of effort: `HIMEM.SYS` needs to deal with hardware specifics, A20 gate handling etc.; the Windows driver doesn’t need to worry about that.

Things get more interesting when more complex memory managers are loaded. Such memory managers can only run Windows in enhanced mode if they implement [the Global Expanded Memory Manager Import interface](https://www.drdobbs.com/windows/undocumented-corner/184409317), which allows Windows to retrieve all the necessary runtime information from a pre-existing memory manager.

In some cases more dubious shenanigans are required. For example, Windows 3.0 standard mode refuses to run if another enhanced memory manager is already loaded; to work around this, QEMM386 patches the Windows DOS extender (`DOSX.EXE`) as it loads!

---

¹ Including Microsoft’s own `XMSMMGR.EXE`, which is used during Windows setup on systems that don’t already have XMS.

Comment: Your answer provides the both reasons why Windows requires the base XMS driver: To know which parts of the extended memory are still free (i.e. not used by smartdrv, a RAM disk or other programs using extended memory), and to abstract controlling the A20 gate.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that it required himem simply
because it had to support himem, to start with.
I.e. if you have himem.sys loaded, then windows can't
just look into e820 and map all the available memory.
It needs to allocate if from himem. If you support
also the no-himem case, then you'll need an entirely
different code path, which needs to be maintained and
tested. So probably they just wanted to reduce the
maintenance burden and not introduce the second code
path.

Another interesting scenario may be that windows
used the big real mode during startup - that mode
is set up by himem.sys if it itself was started in
real mode. (of course this doesn't apply to the case
when also emm386 is loaded, which needs an entirely
different startup technique)

Yet another possibility is that windows just wanted
to keep as much free conventional memory as possible,
or otherwise many DOS programs would OOM in its DOS
boxes. So it insisted on loading himem.sys, but this
is less likely to be the reason because IIRC the
`DOS=HIGH` wasn't a requirement.

One more thing I can very vaguely recall, is that
there were non-standard PCs with the vendor-specific
a20 gating implemented in a custom himem.sys from vendor.
In that case loading himem.sys would be a mandatory.

Comment: This is actually an interesting point.  So much software was DOS only that it was pretty common to boot to the DOS prompt and then run Windows if you needed it until Windows 95.  So in that case you want a memory manager for your DOS programs.

Answer (score 0):

Because until Windows 95 it was not always standard practice to load straight into Windows.

In the Windows 3.x days it was pretty common for only a few of your programs to be Windows apps.  Everything else, and the vast majority of games that weren't Sim City 2000, ran in DOS.  These programs still required more than low memory to run.  So if you could manage to do it all in one autoexec.bat it was pretty common for the boot process to leave you at a DOS prompt with himem or some other memory manager running and let you invoke windows from the PATH if you needed to run Word or whatever.

It was also still pretty common to need a boot menu or boot disk with different startup config to get games running.  Windows and games memory requirements were not particularly friendly to eachother.